# How to Prove Triangle Centers in Tetrahedra

Tags: proof-writing, triangles, centroid

How would you prove the existence of triangle centers in tetrahedra, for example, the incenter, circumcenter, or centroid?

Comment: Several of the definitions for the centers carry over directly (with no change).  For example, the centroid can be defined by a formula from calculus.

Comment: True, but I think the OP wants proof that the line from a vertex to the centroid of the opposite face passes through the centroid of the tetrahedron.

Answer (score 0):

By construction. For example the incenter, if it exists, is the point equidistant from all 4 faces. Construct it as the intersection of 3 of the 6 bisector planes, to be chosen so that the 3 corresponding edges do not meet in one vertex, and conclude that this intersection must lay at the same distance to all 6 faces (so that it automatically lies on the other 3 bisector planes as well).